# Filling JQuery autocomplete with PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm a relative noob to JavaScript and JQuery, but I've been searching the web for hours to find an answer to this question. I'm trying to populate a JQuery autocomplete function using an array I've made in PHP. This is a snippet of the array:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        "Abaddon" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/abad_blink_01.mp3",
        "Alchemist" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/alch_blink_01.mp3",
        "Anti Mage" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/anti_blink_01.mp3",
        "Ancient Apparition" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/appa_blink_01.mp3",
        "Axe" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/axe_blink_01.mp3", 
    );
?>
```

And here is the script I'm trying to run:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>

        $( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags;
        });

    });
</script>
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="BlinkDaggerQuiz.php" class="answer_box">
    <p>Which hero is it?  <input type="text" id="auto" name="guess" /></p>
</form>
```

And my head tags:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BlinkDaggerQuiz.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing; the autocomplete options will not show in the text box. I've also tried substituting `implode()` for the `json_encode()`, but got the same non-results.

Comment: What does the actual (rendered) page source look like at `var availableTags`? Is that variable getting set properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your current code should be returning some syntax errors. Hit F12 and find out.

You appear to be trying to use the [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget from jQuery UI. There is no autocomplete feature built into plain old jQuery so you will have to include jQuery UI as well.

This part is JavaScript:

```
$( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags;
    });
});
```

This means `availableTags` needs to be a JavaScript array as well. The easiest syntax for JavaScript arrays is `var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];`.

You need to output your PHP array into a JavaScript array which can be done with the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function. If given an array, the `implode` function will join all **values** in that array. In your case you want the **keys** of the array to be in the array instead of the **values**. So you can use the [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to retrieve all the keys in the given array. You will end up with:

```
var availableTags = [<?php echo '"' . implode ('","', array_keys ($arr)) . '"'; ?>];
```

When your page loads you should end up with a proper JavaScript array:

```
var availableTags = ["Abaddon","Alchemist", "Anti Mage", "Ancient Apparition", "Axe"];
```

To my knowledge there are no Dota heroes with double quotes in their names so using double quotes as strings should be fine..

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of the separate jquery-ui files I needed to add. It works excellently, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure linked with under file

```
<!-- html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

autocomplete function work for array like

`var availableTags = ["Abaddon","Alchemist", "Anti Mage", "Ancient Apparition", "Axe"];`

so you need to change look like this as you need..

```
<?php
$new_arr = array();
$arr = array(
    "Abaddon" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/abad_blink_01.mp3",
    "Alchemist" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/alch_blink_01.mp3",
    "Anti Mage" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/anti_blink_01.mp3",
    "Ancient Apparition" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/appa_blink_01.mp3",
    "Axe" => "/BlinkDaggerSounds/axe_blink_01.mp3", 
);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new_arr[] = $key;// or $value
    }
?>
<script>
$(function() {

    var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($new_arr); ?>


   $("#auto").autocomplete({
       // source: availableTags;  // autocomplete source is not include ";" (semicolon)
          source: availableTags   //correct
   });

});
</script>
```